# Setting the GridView Selected item to none

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, winrt-xaml

I am developing windows 8.1 app using Xaml and c#, Windows 8.1 selectes the first list item when the list loads. How can i Change this so that the list has no selectedItem when it loads.

Comment: just set SelectedIndex = -1

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN documentation:

> Use the SelectedIndex property to determine the index of the currently selected row in a >GridView control. You can also use this property to programmatically select a row in the >control. To clear the selection of a row, set this property to -1.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In my case, setting the `SelectedIndex` to -1 did not work. If you are populating your GridView from a CollectionViewSource, you have to insert this line in the GridView :

`IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"`

From MSDN

> **Selection behavior and CollectionViewSource**
>
> List controls that derive from Selector have a default selection behavior that depends on what the items source is (the type that's used for ItemsSource). If the items source is a CollectionViewSource instance, then the behavior in the selection control is that the selection will default to the current item. When the list is first displayed, **the selection defaults to the first item as current item**. **If you don't want the first item to be selected in this case, set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem to false** in the GridView.